# How to determine the OS

Tags: delphi, operating-system

how to implement a function that will return the OS name? detect the environment where the program running on?

win2000/xp/vista/win7 etc...?

Comment: I think the OP got more information than he could ever have dreamt about! :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Something like this:

```
function osver: string;
begin
  result := 'Unknown (Windows ' + IntToStr(Win32MajorVersion) + '.' + IntToStr(Win32MinorVersion) + ')';
  case Win32MajorVersion of
    4:
      case Win32MinorVersion of
        0: result := 'Windows 95';
        10: result := 'Windows 98';
        90: result := 'Windows ME';
      end;
    5:
      case Win32MinorVersion of
        0: result := 'Windows 2000';
        1: result := 'Windows XP';
      end;
    6:
      case Win32MinorVersion of
        0: result := 'Windows Vista';
        1: result := 'Windows 7';
        2: result := 'Windows 8';
        3: result := 'Windows 8.1';
      end;
    10:
      case Win32MinorVersion of
        0: result := 'Windows 10';
      end;
  end;
end;
```

There is really no need to call `GetVersionEx` because `SysUtils.pas` has `InitPlatformID` in its `initialization` clause. Hence the global constants `Win32MajorVersion` and `Win32MinorVersion` (and friends) will be populated already.

Comment: Be very careful what you do with separate major/minor version numbers. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/13/72476.aspx

Comment: @Daniel Earwicker: Yes, I know it is not the complete story (that's why I wrote "something like this"). But it is definitely a good start.

Comment: This one is also missing Server operating system detection.

Comment: @Warren P: Yes, I know it is not the complete story (that's why I wrote "something like this"). But it is definitely a good start.

Comment: @PureScience: "Win32" is the name of the Windows API, even if the OS is 64-bit.

Answer (score 11):

As alternative to the Win32 API, you can use the WMI [`Win32_OperatingSystem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394239%28VS.85%29.aspx) Class.

you can write a simple function like this to retrieve the operating windows version name.

```
function  GetWin32_OSName:string;
var
  objWMIService : OLEVariant;
  colItems      : OLEVariant;
  colItem       : OLEVariant;
  oEnum         : IEnumvariant;
  iValue        : LongWord;

  function GetWMIObject(const objectName: String): IDispatch;
  var
    chEaten: Integer;
    BindCtx: IBindCtx;
    Moniker: IMoniker;
  begin
    OleCheck(CreateBindCtx(0, bindCtx));
    OleCheck(MkParseDisplayName(BindCtx, StringToOleStr(objectName), chEaten, Moniker));
    OleCheck(Moniker.BindToObject(BindCtx, nil, IDispatch, Result));
  end;

begin
  objWMIService := GetWMIObject('winmgmts:\\localhost\root\cimv2');
  colItems      := objWMIService.ExecQuery('SELECT Caption FROM Win32_OperatingSystem','WQL',0);
  oEnum         := IUnknown(colItems._NewEnum) as IEnumVariant;
  if oEnum.Next(1, colItem, iValue) = 0 then
  Result:=colItem.Caption; //The caption property return an  string  wich includes the operating system version. For example, "Microsoft Windows XP Professional Version = 5.1.2500". 
end;
```

Addionally you can retrieve more info about the Windows version using the others properties of the Win32_OperatingSystem Class.

Check this code

```
program GetWMI_Win32_OperatingSystem;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils
  ,ActiveX
  ,ComObj
  ,Variants;


Procedure  GetWin32_OperatingSystem;
var
  objWMIService : OLEVariant;
  colItems      : OLEVariant;
  colItem       : OLEVariant;
  oEnum         : IEnumvariant;
  iValue        : LongWord;

  function GetWMIObject(const objectName: String): IDispatch;
  var
    chEaten: Integer;
    BindCtx: IBindCtx;
    Moniker: IMoniker;
  begin
    OleCheck(CreateBindCtx(0, bindCtx));
    OleCheck(MkParseDisplayName(BindCtx, StringToOleStr(objectName), chEaten, Moniker));
    OleCheck(Moniker.BindToObject(BindCtx, nil, IDispatch, Result));
  end;

begin
  objWMIService := GetWMIObject('winmgmts:\\localhost\root\cimv2');
  colItems      := objWMIService.ExecQuery('SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem','WQL',0);
  oEnum         := IUnknown(colItems._NewEnum) as IEnumVariant;
  if oEnum.Next(1, colItem, iValue) = 0 then
  begin
    Writeln('Caption        '+colItem.Caption);
    Writeln('Version        '+colItem.Version);
    Writeln('BuildNumber    '+colItem.BuildNumber);
    Writeln('BuildType      '+colItem.BuildType);
    Writeln('CodeSet        '+colItem.CodeSet);
    Writeln('CountryCode    '+colItem.CountryCode);
    Writeln('BootDevice     '+colItem.BootDevice);
    Writeln;
  end;
end;


function  GetWin32_OSName:string;
var
  objWMIService : OLEVariant;
  colItems      : OLEVariant;
  colItem       : OLEVariant;
  oEnum         : IEnumvariant;
  iValue        : LongWord;

  function GetWMIObject(const objectName: String): IDispatch;
  var
    chEaten: Integer;
    BindCtx: IBindCtx;
    Moniker: IMoniker;
  begin
    OleCheck(CreateBindCtx(0, bindCtx));
    OleCheck(MkParseDisplayName(BindCtx, StringToOleStr(objectName), chEaten, Moniker));
    OleCheck(Moniker.BindToObject(BindCtx, nil, IDispatch, Result));
  end;

begin
  objWMIService := GetWMIObject('winmgmts:\\localhost\root\cimv2');
  colItems      := objWMIService.ExecQuery('SELECT Caption FROM Win32_OperatingSystem','WQL',0);
  oEnum         := IUnknown(colItems._NewEnum) as IEnumVariant;
  if oEnum.Next(1, colItem, iValue) = 0 then
  Result:=colItem.Caption;
end;

begin
 try
    CoInitialize(nil);
    try
      GetWin32_OperatingSystem;
      //Writeln(GetWin32_OSName);
      Readln;
    finally
    CoUninitialize;
    end;
 except
    on E:Exception do
    Begin
        Writeln(E.Classname, ': ', E.Message);
        Readln;
    End;
  end;
end.
```

Comment: GetWin32_OSName was what I m looking for since 2000s :) shorty and best. thanks for save my day.

Comment: Notice that this is only supported on Vista or higher.

Answer (score 4):

I use this in my programs:

```
{$J+}
TYPE
  TOperatingSystemClass = (osUntested,osUnknown,osWin95,osWin98,osWinME,osWinNT,osWin2000,osWinXP,osWinXPSP1,osWinXPSP2,osWinXPSP3,osWin2003,osWinVista,osWinVistaSP1,osWinVistaSP2,osWinVistaSP3,osWin7,osWin7SP1,osWin7SP2,osWin7SP3,osHigher);

FUNCTION OperatingSystemClass : TOperatingSystemClass;
  CONST
    OSClass     : TOperatingSystemClass = osUntested;

  VAR
    Info        : OSVERSIONINFOEX;
    OldInfo : OSVERSIONINFO ABSOLUTE Info;

  BEGIN
    IF OSClass=osUntested THEN BEGIN
      FillChar(Info,SizeOf(Info),0);
      Info.dwOSVersionInfoSize:=SizeOf(Info); OSClass:=osUnknown;
      IF NOT GetVersionEx(OldInfo) THEN BEGIN
        FillChar(OldInfo,SizeOf(OldInfo),0);
        OldInfo.dwOSVersionInfoSize:=SizeOf(OldInfo);
        GetVersionEx(OldInfo)
      END;
      CASE Info.dwPlatformId OF
        VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_WINDOWS      : CASE Info.dwMajorVersion OF
                                              3 : OSClass:=osWin95;
                                              4 : CASE Info.dwMinorVersion OF
                                                     0 : OSClass:=osWin95;
                                                    10 : OSClass:=osWin98
                                                  ELSE // OTHERWISE //
                                                    OSClass:=osWinME
                                                  END
                                          END;
        VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_NT           : CASE Info.dwMajorVersion OF
                                              5 : CASE Info.dwMinorVersion OF
                                                    0 : OSClass:=osWin2000;
                                                    1 : OSClass:=osWinXP;
                                                    2 : OSClass:=osWin2003
                                                  END;
                                              6 : IF Info.dwMinorVersion=0 THEN
                                                    OSClass:=osWinVista
                                                  ELSE IF Info.dwMinorVersion=1 THEN
                                                    OSClass:=osWin7
                                                  ELSE
                                                    OSClass:=osHigher
                                            END
      END;
      IF (OSClass IN [osWinXP,osWinVista,osWin7]) AND (Info.wServicePackMajor>0) THEN
        INC(OSClass,MAX(Info.wServicePackMajor,3))
    END;
    Result:=OSClass
  END;
```

where

```
type
  OSVERSIONINFOEX = packed record
    dwOSVersionInfoSize: DWORD;
    dwMajorVersion: DWORD;
    dwMinorVersion: DWORD;
    dwBuildNumber: DWORD;
    dwPlatformId: DWORD;
    szCSDVersion: Array [0..127 ] of Char;
    wServicePackMajor: WORD;
    wServicePackMinor: WORD;
    wSuiteMask: WORD;
    wProductType: BYTE;
    wReserved: BYTE;
  End;
  TOSVersionInfoEx = OSVERSIONINFOEX;
  POSVersionInfoEx = ^TOSVersionInfoEx;
```

Comment: FYI: It's missing Windows Server Operating Systems.

Answer (score 4):

If you want obtain more information about de Operating System, you can use WMI (the code of RRUZ use it for the name). For more information you can use the component **COperatingSystemInfo** of [GLibWMI](http://sourceforge.net/projects/glibwmi/) (from Sourceforge or [Author WebPage](http://neftali.clubdelphi.com/?p=589) (mine) ;-D ).
All the library is free and sourve code avaible. For OperatingSystem you can obtain this properties:

[alt text http://a.imageshack.us/img594/1660/coperatinsysteminfo.png](http://a.imageshack.us/img594/1660/coperatinsysteminfo.png)

Regards

Answer (score 2):

Since [Delphi XE2](https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/new-tosversion-type-in-delphi-xe2-39273) you can use `TOSVersion` record. Note, that it is a global record and [you cannot create TOSVersion objects](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.SysUtils.TOSVersion).

For example:

```
lblVersion.Caption := TOSVersion.ToString;
```

You have few record properties available to use: `Minor`, `Major`, `Build`, `Architecture` provided together with `Platform` which you can use to make sure that the operating system is Windows.

To compare the current version of the system with defined one, use `Check` version.

Answer (score 1):

The [JCL](http://www.delphi-jedi.org/) contains this enumerated type:

```
  TWindowsVersion =
   (wvUnknown, wvWin95, wvWin95OSR2, wvWin98, wvWin98SE, wvWinME,
    wvWinNT31, wvWinNT35, wvWinNT351, wvWinNT4, wvWin2000, wvWinXP,
    wvWin2003, wvWinXP64, wvWin2003R2, wvWinVista, wvWinServer2008,
    wvWin7, wvWinServer2008R2);
```

It contains this function, and others:

```
function GetWindowsVersion: TWindowsVersion;
```

[Documentation here](http://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/JCL_Help%3aGetWindowsVersion)

What's even better, when a new version of Windows comes out, someone will update the JCL and you won't have to extend this code yourself.  Also, of all the answers to this question, only the JCL handles Windows Server operating system detection, in addition to the usual windows end-user versions.

Answer (score 0):

```
function OS_IsWindowsXP: Boolean;
begin
 Result:= (Win32MajorVersion= 5) AND (Win32MinorVersion= 1);
end;

function OS_IsWindowsXPUp: Boolean;
begin
 Result:= ((Win32MajorVersion = 5) AND (Win32MinorVersion>= 1))
        OR (Win32MajorVersion>= 6);
end;



function OS_IsWindowsVista: Boolean;
begin
 Result:= (Win32MajorVersion= 6) AND (Win32MinorVersion= 0);
end;

function OS_IsWindowsVistaUp: Boolean;
begin
 Result:= (Win32MajorVersion>= 6);
end;



function OS_IsWindows7: Boolean;
begin
 Result:= (Win32MajorVersion= 6) AND (Win32MinorVersion= 1);
end;

function OS_IsWindows7Up: Boolean;
begin
 Result:= ((Win32MajorVersion = 6) AND (Win32MinorVersion>= 1))   { Any version 6 equal and above Win7 }
        OR (Win32MajorVersion>= 7);                               { Any version above 6 }
end;



function OS_IsWindows8: Boolean;
begin
 Result:= (Win32MajorVersion = 6) AND (Win32MinorVersion= 2);
end;

function OS_IsWindows8Up: Boolean;
begin
 Result:= ((Win32MajorVersion = 6) AND (Win32MinorVersion>= 2))
        OR (Win32MajorVersion>= 7);
end;
```